# What is the Proper Non-blocking Algorithm for Modbus Master on Microcontroller

Tags: algorithm, modbus

Modbus is a a request and response type serial communication. Basically the master send out a request and one of the slave response.

I am modifing the code on a microcontroller which is a master unit on a modbus network. This unit also has a small dot-matrix LCD and some buttons for user interface. The microcontroller is running at 16MHz.

The problem is after the master unit send out a request, it does not know when the slave response, so it may need to wait for a relatively long time. However as this unit has buttons and LCD, it can not wait at a point for too long because the user will feel lag when he pressed a button. The original code is using a RTOS. It seperate  the user interface task and the serial communication tasks so it has no problem. Now I need to change it to non-RTOS code. I have implemented a system tick timer which will interrupt at each 1ms. What is the proper (or common) way to do that?

Comment: You'll have to implement threads and a small pre-emptive scheduler over whatever you do have for an OS ("non-RTOS" and "a microcontroller" is not exactly a lot of information to work with).  It's not a small project, but it's not all that hard either.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do quite a lot with just a single task, especially if you have interrupts. The intermediate position between a single very simple task and an RTOS is a cyclic executive. See http://www3.nd.edu/~cpoellab/teaching/cse40463/slides10.pdf for a brief overview of the spectrum of functionality from a cyclic executive up to a fully preemptive multitasking operating system. You will find much more if you search on this phrase and related phrases, including very sophisticated schemes for making sure that the system never misses its deadlines. If you are an aircraft flight control system, forgetting to check the aircraft pitch angle every X ms can cause problems elsewhere :-)

One way to rewrite code which is naturally multi-threaded is to maintain a model of the state of the system, such as a collection of objects each representing a modbus connection, indexed by a connection id. Then write a routine for every sort of event that can happen, including the arrival of a clock interrupt. When that event happens these routines typically work out which connection is involved, retrieve it from the main collection (or create it from scratch and enter it there if necessary) do the work associated with that particular sort of event, and then return.

It is often convenient to keep a queue of future events, indexed by time, and to have a routine that creates an object representing something to be done at some future time (such as calling a method to check for the expiration of a timeout) and puts this object on the queue.

You need to worry about interrupt processing getting called halfway through an event service routine. One way to deal with this is to lock out interrupts when that could cause a problem. Another way is to have the interrupt routine do nothing more than put an object on a queue that something else will check for later, or just set a flag. Then you need only lock out interrupts when you are checking for items on the queue and removing them.

A number of communications protocols are implemented in this way. Even in a true multitasking operating system you very often don't want to have to create a new thread every time you need to create a new connection. The two main problems with this is that the code is less clear than code which has a thread per object, because stuff that naturally goes together is chopped up into loads of event service events, and if any of the event service methods burn significant amounts of cpu, the system will stall because nothing else will happen when this is going on.